# In Bayesian hierarchical models, what is the difference between an Empirical Bayesian approach to parametrising priors vs using flat hyperpriors

Tags: bayesian, mathematical-statistics, prior, hierarchical-bayesian, empirical-bayes

Say I have a simple hierarchical model, where:

$y_{g,i} = \beta_g x_{g,i} + e_{g,i}$

where $g$ represents the group, $i$ represents the individual within the group, and $e$ is the error. So the variable $x$ has different effects for the different groups.

I want to approach this in a Bayesian way, so I make the following assumption:

$\beta_g \sim f(\mu, \sigma)$, where $f$ is some distribution with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$.

As far as I can tell, I have two options when it comes to parametrising the priors $\mu$ and $\sigma$:

- I could further assume that the priors themselves have some (probably flat) distribution (i.e. use uninformative hyperpriors); or
- I could use the data to obtain point estimates for the average and standard deviation of the group effects of $x$, and assign these as the values of $\mu$ and $\sigma$ respectively (i.e. empirical Bayes).

As far as I can tell, from a philosophical perspective the first approach is preferable, because it lets the Bayesian model 'learn' the distributions of $\mu$ and $\sigma$ from the dataset and doesn't involve looking at the data twice, which I think is generally inadvisable. But in practice:

- Will these approaches lead to different results for our estimates of $\beta_g$? Based on my experience, they will. But why? And will one approach tend to lead to more aggressive pooling/shrinkage than the other?
- Is there ever a *a priori* reason to prefer the empirical Bayes approach (other than maybe a computational one)? If not, why would we ever want to do empirical Bayes when we can just use uninformative hyperpriors and let the Bayesian method figure things out on its own?

Comment: The estimators of $\beta_g$ are difference because $(\mu,\sigma)$ is set to a fixed [data-dependent] value in the empirical Bayes approach, while being random in the hierarchical Bayes version (hence endowed with extra-variability).

Comment: @Xi'an - thanks for the reply. I can how the different approaches differ in terms of how the priors are parametrised, but I'm struggling to understand why they would lead to different results in the specific case that we use uninformative hyperpriors in the hierarchical model. I understand that in this case the distributions we get for the priors $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are based exclusively on the data, which is how we obtain the point estimates under the empirical Bayes approach. So shouldn't the maximum a posteriori values for the priors in the hierarchical approach match the empirical approach?

Comment: The maximum a posteriori values from the joint do not return the empirical Bayes solutions since the latter integrate the $\beta_g$'s out.

Comment: @Xi'an - I think I can kind of see why the results would be different - in the hierarchical solution the priors are uncertain but in the empirical solution they're not. So does this generally imply less weight towards the priors in the former?